# Call an argument name within a function in R

Tags: r, function, arguments, call

I would like to create a generic function `naTrans` that replaces `'NA'` and `''` by `NA`.

The problem is that I can't replace the dataframe `test`in the global environment by the modified `test` dataframe (`mydf`) created within the function. Here's my best try.

```
# Example dataframe containing 'NA'
test <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c('NA', 1:9), 10*10, TRUE), 10))

# My function
naTrans <- function (mydf) {
  mydf[mydf == 'NA' | mydf ==''] <- NA
  assign(deparse(substitute(mydf))[1], mydf, envir = globalenv())
}

test <- naTrans(test)

any(is.na(test))
# [1] FALSE
```

Surely the problem lies in the last line of code `assign(print(deparse(substitute(mydf))), mydf, envir = globalenv())`

Any idea?

Comment: @Tensibai removing the print does not work for me.

Comment: Remove the print (and access the first element from deparse) to give a correct parameter to assign:  `assign(deparse(substitute(mydf))[1], mydf, envir = globalenv())`

Comment: I tried but the original dat frame is not replaced, instead an object named `"structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, "` is created.

Comment: Just a question, why not using the normal way ? (i.e remove the assign in function, and just `test <- naTrans(test)`,

Comment: I tried, but oddly it keeps creating this long-named object instead of replacing `test`

Comment: `mydf %in% c('NA','')` <- this has a problem too as %in% can't work on a df but only on vectors. I would use `mydf == 'NA' | mydf ==''`

Comment: Sure! I edited the question. But the initial problem remains...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the comments in the code are clear enough

```
test <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c('NA',1:9),10*10,T),10))

naTrans <- function (mydf) {
      mydf[mydf == 'NA' | mydf == ''] <- NA # use and or opertor, %in% don't work on DF but on vectors
      return(mydf) # return the modified mydf (the return is optionnal, you may just use mydf here 
}

test <- naTrans(test) # replace actual object by caller.
```

Comment: Sure, why did I not think of it?? :)